# User Registration using volley library in Android

Tags: java, android

Using a volley library I am sending a post request to a file register.php which should perform user registration and return JSONResponse after success. The code I have written is working fine in the local server(MAMP) but is not working in the live server. Logcat shows {success = 0} in the live server.

````
    package com.example.androidregisterandlogin;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private EditText name, email, password, c_password;
        private Button btn_regist;
        private ProgressBar loading;
        RequestQueue requestQueue;

        private static String URL_REGIST = "https://domainname.com.np/mentordai/register.php";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            loading = findViewById(R.id.loading);
            name = findViewById(R.id.name);
            email = findViewById(R.id.email);
            password = findViewById(R.id.password);
            c_password = findViewById(R.id.c_password);
            btn_regist = findViewById(R.id.btn_regist);

            btn_regist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Regist();
                }
            });

        }

        private void Regist(){
            loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn_regist.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            final String name = this.name.getText().toString().trim();
            final String email = this.email.getText().toString().trim();
            final String password = this.password.getText().toString().trim();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_REGIST,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try{
                                Log.d("TAG",response);
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                                if (success.equals("1")) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Register Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Register Error! " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                btn_regist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Register Error! " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btn_regist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    })

            {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("name", name);
                    params.put("email", email);
                    params.put("password", password);
                    return params;
                }
            };

            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


        }
    }


    Server code

    <?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST'){

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        require_once 'connect.php';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO student_users_table (name, email, password) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$password')";

        if ( mysqli_query($connection, $sql) ) {
            $result["success"] = "1";
            $result["message"] = "success";

            echo json_encode($result);
            mysqli_close($connection);

        } else {

            $result["success"] = "0";
            $result["message"] = "error";

            echo json_encode($result);
            mysqli_close($connection);
       }
    }
    ?>

```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an php expert but it looks like your server is the one who return the 'success=0'
And it looks like you have some problem with the `if ( mysqli_query($connection, $sql) )` statement, your code going to the else who return the `success = 0`.
Try to debug the server to see what happens when you send register request.

Comment: Thank you, Maksim. I have upgraded my volley to com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1 and success = 1 was returned by the server but data was not inserted and with the same code I tried it with another server(Godaddy) it worked.

Comment: So now it is ok after the upgrade?

Comment: It is not due to upgrade of volley library but changing the hosting platform had actually worked. Can you help in this it shows underline in AuthFaliureError and says 'com.android.volley.AuthFaliureError' is never thrown in the method and also while committing it shows warning

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put validation at both end (Client as well as server end) on all of your form field . If any one of the field is kept empty your query will not be able to run.

For Validation in server use this at the start of your code

```
if( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
}
```

To Validate data in Client side use

```
if(this.name.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
{
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Name " + e.toString(),                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

also for password and email